# How to say "clean up" (for example a house or a room) in Japanese?

Tags: translation

I'm trying to compose a sentence which starts with: パーティーが終{お}わる時{とき}に～.. I want to say "After the party is over, it is hard to clean up the house". Can you help me?

Comment: I think one of the most natural ways to say "hard to clean up" is "なかなか片付かない”.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also use [片付]{かた・づ}ける for "clean/tidy up".

Although there is overlap, I tend to think of 掃除 as a more subjective cleaning—turning something from "dirty" to "clean"; wiping up spills, throwing out trash, etc.

For 片付ける, I think of a more abstract "cleaning up", putting things away/back in order, clearing stuff away, etc.

Answer (score 1):

掃除{そうじ｝　is the word you're looking for.

パーティーが終｛お｝わった後｛あと｝に家｛いえ｝の掃除｛そうじ｝が難｛むずか｝しくなる。
After the party ends, it becomes hard to clean the house.